# AngularJS select option dont pass value into http post request

Tags: angularjs, select

I have select box where i pass data using angular constant. I got 2 different types how i wrote it because i was trying to solve my problem but unsuccessfully. Problem is that my select box doesnt pass any value into post request and i have no idea why. I also tried it using ng-option but with same result.

```
(function () {
app.constant("Constants", {
    Status: {
        1 : "New",
        2 : "Active",
        3 : "OnHold",
        4 : "Testing",
        5 : "Finished",
        6 : "Dropped"
    },
    Priority: [
        { id: "1", name: "Low" },
        { id: "2", name: "Medium" },
        { id: "3", name: "High" },
        { id: "4", name: "Urgent" },
    ],
});
```

Here i bind those enums to scope in my angular controller

```
    $scope.priority = {
        model: null,
        options: Constants.Priority,
    }
    $scope.status = {
        model: null,
        options: Constants.Status,
    }
```

Here is my view where i use those data coming from my controller for my form. I use ng-repeat according to official angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Status</label>
    <select name="status_select" id="status_select" ng-model="status.model" class="form-control">
         <option ng-repeat="x in status.options" value="{{x.id}}">{{x}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Am i missing something why its not working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Status is an object, you don't have any `id` !

use ng-options

```
<select ng-model="status.model" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in status.options">
</select>
```

or ng-repeat like this:

```
<select ng-model="status.model">
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in status.options" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for quick respond, i tried this but unfortunately its not working for me. It still sends everything except my values from those select boxes. It must be some silly mistake in my code but i cant see it for now.

Comment: @Martin please create plunker of your code for more help

Comment: I solved it already. I made a silly mistake. I assigned my select box to wrong model. I checked it in ng-inspector which i installed and saw it.
I had to use this ng-model <select ng-model="project.status">